Mule 4 cache expiry - when does the cache exactly expire?
In my implementation I need to invoke an api which needs a token to be supplied .
This token has a life of 15 minutes .
So what I was implementing was an inmemory cache with the cache expiring after 13 minutes , thereby after cache expires will regenerate the token and then store in cache
Here is the code where call to create token is enclosed within cache:
    <sub-flow name="common-root-get-access-token-subflow">
        <ee:cache doc:name="access token cache" cachingStrategy-ref="Token_Caching_Strategy">
            <flow-ref doc:name="Call token endpoint" name="create token" />
        </ee:cache>
        <set-variable value="#[payload.access_token]" doc:name="assign access token"  
        variableName="rootAccessToken" />
    </sub-flow>

The cache is defined as below:
    <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Token_Caching_Strategy" doc:name="Caching Strategy"  
        keyGenerationExpression="abcd">
        <os:private-object-store alias="tokenCache" persistent="false" maxEntries="1" 
        entryTtl="13" entryTtlUnit="MINUTES" expirationInterval="13" 
        expirationIntervalUnit="MINUTES"/>
    </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>

With above config what was observed is :
#1 It seems the cache was expiring after 23 minutes and NOT 13 . So based on this article I thought that the duration of cache is 13 min TTL + interval 13 min = 26 min ( ref here )
#2 Next tried with ttl = 3 min , interval = 2 min
Cache was expiring every 4 minutes ( here I am assuming that due to 2 min interval on first 2 min the cache had not expired but on second 2 min interval = 4th min the cache had expired so it was expiring cache )
#3 Next tried with ttl = 3 min , interval = 1 min
Cache expiring at every 4th minute....
Think the real life of cache is 3 min but the interval at which it is checked is 1 min
so ideally at end of 3rd minute cache should expire , but probably since life of cache is 3 and time of check 3 is coinciding Mule is probably not expiring cache at 3rd minute
Rather at next check after 1 min = 4th minute the cache is being expired looks like ........
#4 Next tried with ttl = 3 min , interval = 3 min 5 sec
cache seems to be expiring at every 6 min and 5 seconds and NOT affter every 3 min 5 seconds which I was expecting .....
#5 Next tried with ttl = 3 min , interval = 1 min 5 sec
IN this case it seemed to be have as I was expecting where cache was expiring about after every 3 min and somewhere between 5-15 seconds
So my understanding has been that TTL defines the actual life of cache BUT when the cache actually expires is detremined by the defined interval
#5 seems to be in line with my expectation
#1 is probably also the same where since TTL and interval is 13 min , maybe Mule is not removing objects from cache at the 13th minute but at next interval ( 13 + 13 = 26th min )
#2 and #3  is also inline with above
#4 seems an outlier , I am not sure why ?
also the ref link here seems to indicate cache will expire after ttl + interval
My environment is Mule 4.4.6 runtime with Java 8 and am using Studio 7.16
Can someone please confirm the way cache will expire ?
If my token is supposed to expire in 15 minutes can I plan to expire my cache after 13 min by keeping TTL = 12 min 30 seconds and interval = 1 min ?
Edit1 tried enabling cache debug logs but was disappointed where I was expecting some kind of background thread to be running and getting logged ( like a garbage collector thread where at the specified interval it would run and specify whether cache is a candidate to be expired or not )

Yeah you have got it right. The ttl determines the actual life of each separate entry. And the expirationInterval determine the frequency of the background thread at which it will check for outdated entries in the object store. Therefore the entryTtl + expirationInterval is the maximum time a key will be present in the os. The minimum time is the entryTtl itself.
The configuration TTL = 12 min 30 seconds and interval = 1 min should work fine. You can expect a key to be there for a maximum of 13min and 30sec, and for atleast 12min 30sec.
I do not understand how #4 is an outlier based on your explaination of #1,#2,#3. The ttl is 3 min and interval is 3min5sec so an entry can be active for maximum 6min5sec

thanks @harshank for the confirmation , the confusion regarding #4 is with ttl of 3 min and interval of 3 min 5 sec , lets say we add something to cache at 11:00 AM , then at 11:03 AM the cache should now become stale / eligibible for removal and at 11:03:05 interval the thread should evict the cache but that does not happen  ( which I think it should ) , and hence also not clear when you state that the cache can be active for max 6 min 5 sec ? why should the cache not get evicted at 3 min 5 second itself ?

Can you tell me how you are calculating these? I ran a test project and it is working as expected for me.
